# How to display select (manytomany) as thumbnails?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have models:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product/", null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    [...]

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    decsription = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImage, blank=True, null=True)
    [...]
```

and I want do display multiselect (on edit product page in admin) as thumbnails with name. How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiselect"?

Comment: <select name="my_name" multiple>

Answer (score 0):

My workaround, in admin:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        images = ProductImage.objects.all()
        items = []
        for image in images:
            items.append(
                (image.pk, mark_safe('%s' % image.image.url))
            )
        self.fields['images'].choices = items

class ProductAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm

site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

and override base.html:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#id_images').css('width', '400px').css('height', '400px');
    jQuery('#id_images option').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('style', 'background: url('+jQuery(this).text()+') no-repeat; background-size: 70px 70px; height: 80px; padding-left: 80px; line-height: 80px;');
    });
});
```